# How to create transitive properties usingh Jena schema?

Tags: properties, jena

I basically want to do this using Jena:

i) Schema

```
class:LivingBeing type owl:Class
prop:PrimeFeatures

class:Animal type owl:Class
prop:Speed typeOf PrimeFeatures
prop:Nature typeOf PrimeFeatures

class:HumanBeing type owl:Class
prop:Intelligence typeOf PrimeFeatures
```

ii) Data

```
Individual:Cat typeOf Animal resource="someuri:Cat"
prop:Speed = 100
prop:Nature = violent
prop:Veg = No

Individual:John typeOf HumanBeing resource="someuri:John"
prop:Intelligence = Average



Resource resourcecat = model.getResource("someuri:Cat") ;
```

Using above schema and data, I want to answer following kinds of needs for resourcecat:
Get PrimeFeatures of resourcecat : I should get both the names of the Properties which are PrimeFeatures for Cat and their values.
So, I should get following:-

```
           PrimeFeatures(catresource):
           speed=100
           nature=violent
```

Also, I should be able to modify the prime features of the Animal class using the Animal class schema.

Basically I want to control the data which I fetch using the schema. 
Mostly using OntClass, Resource and Properties. I know it must be possible using Jena.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution appears below. However, I would caution that you're not really using the characteristics of OWL and RDF in the way they were designed. If you really want to to make use of Jena's capabilities, you should read more about semantic web technology and use that to guide your design. Otherwise, you might as well design a custom solution just for your application using Java, rather than try to force-fit your design into a representation where it doesn't really fit.

```
package test;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class User1374179_Test
{
    public static String ns = "http://example.org/test#";

    private OntClass livingBeing;
    private OntClass animal;
    private OntProperty primeFeatures;
    private OntProperty speed;
    private OntProperty nature;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new User1374179_Test().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = createSchema();
        showClassProperties( livingBeing );
        showClassProperties( animal );

        Individual cat1 = createInstance( m, animal, "cat1" );
        cat1.addProperty( speed, m.createTypedLiteral( 100 ));
        cat1.addProperty( nature, "violent" );
        showInstanceProperties( cat1, animal );
    }

    private OntModel createSchema() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF );


        livingBeing = m.createClass( ns + "LivingBeing" );
        primeFeatures = m.createOntProperty( ns + "primeFeatures" );
        primeFeatures.addDomain( livingBeing );

        animal = m.createClass( ns + "Animal" );
        animal.addSuperClass( livingBeing );

        speed = m.createOntProperty( ns + "speed" );
        speed.addSuperProperty( primeFeatures );
        speed.addDomain( animal );

        nature = m.createOntProperty( ns + "nature" );
        nature.addSuperProperty( primeFeatures );
        nature.addDomain( animal );

        return m;
    }

    private Individual createInstance( OntModel m, OntClass cls, String name ) {
        return m.createIndividual( ns + name, cls );
    }

    private void showClassProperties( OntClass c ) {
        System.out.println( "Class " + c.getURI() );
        for (ExtendedIterator<OntProperty> i = c.listDeclaredProperties(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            System.out.println( " .. has property " + i.next() );
        }
    }

    private void showInstanceProperties( OntResource r, OntClass c ) {
        System.out.println( "Instance " + r.getURI() + " has properties: " );
        for (ExtendedIterator<OntProperty> i = c.listDeclaredProperties(true); i.hasNext(); ) {
            OntProperty p = i.next();
            System.out.println( p.getURI() + " ==> " + r.getPropertyValue( p ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Class http://example.org/test#LivingBeing
 .. has property http://example.org/test#primeFeatures
Class http://example.org/test#Animal
 .. has property http://example.org/test#speed
 .. has property http://example.org/test#primeFeatures
 .. has property http://example.org/test#nature
Instance http://example.org/test#cat1 has properties: 
http://example.org/test#speed ==> 100^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int
http://example.org/test#nature ==> violent
```

Comment: Hi Ian Thanks a ton. The only thing I need more is how to get the primefeatures exactly. Can you help me create a function like showInstancePrimeFeatureProperties instead of showInstanceProperties. A function which lists names of all properties which are primefeatures along with their values?